# ejecutar funcion al cerrar (cancelar) la ventana que abre input file

Tags: jquery, html

Tengo un input file común y corriente. Que al presionar te abre la ventana correspondiente para elegir un archivo de tu computadora.

Tengo una función que me carga un gif de "cargando" cuando le das clic al botón del input; y al seleccionar la imagen y procesar el envío de la imagen por ajax al servidor este gif se oculta.

Pero cómo oculto el gif si el usuario da "cancelar" o cierra la ventana sin elegir archivo?

El gif lo oculto al seleccionar y procesar un input file porque se lanza el evento onchange.

Cómo puedo hacerle?

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
```

JS:

```
 $("#file").on("click", function(){
  $(".gif").show();

});
$("#file").on("change", function(){

$.ajax({
    ...,
complete(){
    $(".gif").hide();
    }
});

});
```

Comment: Esto es lo más acertado que he llegado a implementar, puesto que el navegador no le dice a JS cuando el usuario cierra la ventana (por el método que sea) y este no selecciona un archivo para subir. http://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6/

Comment: Hola, Lixus. La forma en la que lo haces es la más interesante que he encontrado, pero pasa algo, aunque cargues un archivo, la primera vez siempre te mandará el alert de empty wheeze, a qué crees que se deba?

Comment: Le he puesto un await sleep(2000); y parece funcionar perfectamente. Gracias, Lixus!

Comment: Ponlo como respuesta, porfa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto es lo más acertado que he llegado a implementar, puesto que el navegador no le dice a JS cuando el usuario cierra la ventana (por el método que sea) y este no selecciona un archivo para subir :

[Aqui el ejemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/Shiboe/yuK3r/6)

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurren 2 maneras de hacerlo:

**1.** Puedes agregarle un evento al botón cerrar de la ventana modal para que ocultes tu gif (*La mejor opcion*).

**2.** Crear una funcion que pregunte cada X tiempo si la modal es visible. Si no lo es entonces ocultas el gif:

```
$("#file").on("change", function(){

 var id = setInterval(function(){

         if(!$("#id-modal").is(":visible")) {
           $(".gif").hide();
           clearInterval(id);
        }
 });

//..

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Esta es una forma que me sirvió a mi; es una de las opciones que menciona @Einer solo que se tomo la ventana window que genera el input `file`

https://jsfiddle.net/cromerog/1b3seqrw/7/

Lo que se realiza es que se verifica si la ventana tiene el foco; si pierde el foco (cancela, presiona `ESC` o se selecciona un archivo) se envía a ocultar el `gif`.

El `<span id="status">` simulara como se mostraría/ocultaría el `gif`.

```js
$(function() {

    $("#status").hide();
    var window_focus;
 
    $(window).focus(function() {
     window_focus = true;
    }).blur(function() {
        window_focus = false;
    });
   
    $( "#archivo" ).bind( "click", function() {
        $(".gif").show();
        $("#status").show();
     var loopFocus = setInterval(function() {
            if (window_focus) {
          clearInterval(loopFocus);
                $(".gif").hide();
                $("#status").hide();
                if ($("#archivo").val() === ''){
                    alert('Cancelado o Esc!');
                }
            }
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="prueba.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Archivo:</p>
    <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo" required/>
    <br>
    <br>
    <hr>
    <span id="status" class="hidden">Esperando un Click</span>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Tomado como ejemplo de:
https://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/556543-evento-ao-cancelar-input-file-com-jquery/?do=findComment&comment=2220313

Answer (score 0):

El error en tú código es que tu muestras el `gif` independimiente si se realiza la acción o no, sin mencionar que el gif sólo se muestra si el usuario le da click al input, fallaría en mostrarse si el usuario utiliza la tecla `tab' para acceder al input.

La solución es sencilla

```
$("#file").on("change", function(){
$(".gif").show()
$.ajax({
    ...,
complete(){
    $(".gif").hide();
    }
});

});
```

Lo interesante de `onchange` es que solo se llama cuando el valor del input cambia, si el usuario le da cancelar entonces el valor sigue intacto, y no se ejecuta el evento `onchange`.

Comment: Hola, Eduen. No funciona así como lo tienes, el show se muestra hasta que el navegador procese la imagen del input file que se pone en el value del input osea que se queda "congelado" como 4 segundos antes de aparecer el "cargando", en cambio si poneos el show al darle click al input  file sí lo muestra como lo deseo. Gracias igual